# The set of all absolute local maximums of $f$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

The function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ has absolute local maximum in $c$ if  :
There exists $\delta \gt 0 $ such that $ \forall x \space (0 \lt |x-c| \lt \delta) \implies f(x) \lt f(c)$

Prove that the set of all points in which $f$ has absolute local maximum is countable.

Note 1 : Is this method right?  I believe that the set mentioned above, is a subset of all local maximum points of $f$. So, if i prove that "the set of all local maximum points of $f$" is countable, I'm done.  But, if that's true, How can i prove that?

Note 2 : There is [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188264/can-i-prove-that-cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-maximum-point-for-any-function) ( not the same ) to my question but it doesn't have a good answer.

Comment: @CanisLapus and then what happens ?

Comment: The set of rationals is countable.

Comment: What does a "maximum point" mean for you? The same as here but with $f(x)\le f(c)$ instead? There can be uncountably many of _those_, for example for a constant function.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I meant "local maximum points".

Comment: @IStillHaveHope: And what does that mean for you?

Comment: @HenningMakholm The same as here but with $f(x)≤f(c)$ instead :D  Am i wrong?

Comment: @IStillHaveHope: Okay, in that case my previous comment applies.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: First time I hear about "absolute local" maximum. Your definition is just the definition for a local (or relative) maximum.

Comment: @Masacroso actually it's not "my" definition. maybe i used the wrong words when translating, but the question is from the book "Real analysis :  a first course" by Russel Gordon. ( i have the persian version of the book, not the english one ... sorry for that )

Comment: More colloquially, in English we refer to a "*strict* local maximum".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint.** For every $c$ that satisfies the condition, choose a rational number in $(c-\delta,c)$ and another one in $(c,c+\delta)$. No two different absolute local maxima can have the same pair of rationals. Therefore there cannot be more absolute local maxima than there are pairs of rationals.

Comment: Thank you :) fully understood :)